# How might one implement Site-specific Tags?

Tags: django, wagtail

My code shop is developing a multi-tenant Wagtail site, and we'd like each Site to have its own set of tags. We want this so that tags defined by users of Site A don't appear in the autocompleter or the "popular tags" listing for users of Site B.

Would this be possible with a [custom Tag model](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html#custom-tag)? I'm thinking that we could prefix the tag's slugs with the hostname of the current Site, then filter them based on that prefix when pulling tags for the "popular tags" listing or the autocompleter.

If this is not currently possible, could Wagtail be monkey-patched to support it? If so, what code might need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom tag model would be the way to go, yes. One issue you'd currently have to work around (logged here: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3577) is that the autocomplete view is hard-coded to use the default tag model, so to use a custom one you'd need to duplicate [that view](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/85bcd5a176f54b628e6022511a25c10345fd522f/wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/tags.py) in your own app, along with the [`AdminTagWidget`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/85bcd5a176f54b628e6022511a25c10345fd522f/wagtail/wagtailadmin/widgets.py#L88) that references it.